# JDBC Update Statement not working in Netbeans but working in SQL

Tags: jdbc, netbeans, sql-update

I extract data from one database, execute a couple of checks and want to update a table in another database.

My update.executeQuery statement is not working. However when I copy the statement string in SQL and execute it, it does work. What could be wrong with it? (even directions would help me)

Create Update String:

```
public static void createUpdateString() throws SQLException {

    try {
           updateString = "UPDATE ORDER_HEADER SET "
                   + "FRUIT=" + "'" + fruitName+ "',"
                   + "CUSTOMER_NAME =" + "'" + customerName + "'"
                   + " WHERE ORDER_NUMBER = TRIM(" + "'" + orderNumber + "')";

           updateData();
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("ERROR!: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Execute Update Query:

```
public static void updateData() throws SQLException{
    try {
           conn.setAutoCommit(false);
           statementUpdate = conn.createStatement();
           statementUpdate.executeQuery(OrderObject.updateString);
           conn.commit();
           conn.setAutoCommit(true);
           statementUpdate.close();

    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
          System.err.println("Could not process query" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: 'My statement is not working' - exactly what do you mean by that?  Throws an exception?  Has no effect?  Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
          statementUpdate.executeQuery(OrderObject.updateString);
```

looks wrong to me.  Try

```
          statementUpdate.executeUpdate(OrderObject.updateString);
```

instead.

`UPDATE` statements are not queries, so you don't use `executeQuery()` with them.  `executeQuery()` returns a `ResultSet`, but with an `UPDATE` statement there's no data to return.  Instead, you use `executeUpdate()`.  (Note that you also use `executeUpdate()` to run `INSERT` and `DELETE` statements - there aren't any `executeInsert()` nor `executeDelete()` methods on `Statement` objects.)

How databases behave in these situations varies from one database to another.  In particular, the MySQL JDBC driver throws an exception with the following message if you attempt to use `executeQuery()` with an `UPDATE` statement:

> Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()